# Terms for elements of a Modelica path

Tags: terminology, modelica

What is the correct terminology for (elements of a) "Modelica path"? I'm handling and modifying arbitrary "Modelica path"s, so I'm looking for a common terminology.

These are the terms I'm using currently. Example from MSL:

```
Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller
```

1. `Modelica`, `Blocks`, `Examples`, `PID_Controller`: Each of those is a Modelica identifier ([MoSpec 2.3.1](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf))?
2. `Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller`: I call that a "Modelica path" (like the term path is used e.g. in filesystem trees), however what is the correct term for naming a string of concatenated Modelica identifiers? MODELICAPATH is used for library roots in [MoSpec 13.2.4](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf).
3. `Modelica`: When I extract the first element of this complete "Modelica path", is it correct to call it *root path* then?
4. `PID_Controller`: When I extract the last part of the "Modelica path", is it correct to call the resulting string *name* (of a Modelica class)?
5. `Modelica.Blocks.Examples`: Is it correct to call this as *path of the environment* of PID_Controller?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are browsing the Modelica library, and the related Modelica terms are the appropriated classes. So:

1. Modelica, Blocks, Examples are packages PID_Controller is a model.
2. Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller is basically the **fully qualified name** of the model PID_Controller.
3. Modelica is actually a package most people would say the Modelica library.
4. PID_Controller is just the model name.
5. Modelica.Blocks.Examples is package path of the model PID_Controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I'm searching for a general terminology for an arbitrary "Modelica path" (MSL was just an example), so each element can be any specialized Modelica class (e.g. when referencing Components). I've updated my questions to make the generalization in mind more explicit. Nonetheless, #2 seems to be usable as general term. :-)

Comment: The relevant literature(e.g. Fritzson, Tiller) is also using the term fully qualified names.